# Double directory in dropdown

Tags: php

I write this element, but when I want to display the directory in dropown, I have the same directory twice.
LMy first dropdown work well:
blog
image

My second dropdown write the directory twice

blog
image
blog
image

```
        <?php
        //function
        function osc_opendir($path) {
            $path = rtrim($path, '/') . '/';
            $exclude_array = array('.', '..', '.DS_Store', '.directory', '.htaccess', 'Thumbs.db','.php', '_note');
            $result = array();
            if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
              while (false !== ($filename = readdir($handle))) {
                if (!in_array($filename, $exclude_array)) {
                  $file = array('name' => $path . $filename,
                                'is_dir' => is_dir($path . $filename),
                                'writable' => is_writable($path . $filename)
                               );
                  $result[] = $file;
                  if ($file['is_dir'] == true) {
                $result = array_merge($result, osc_opendir($path . $filename));
                  }
                }
              }
              closedir($handle);
            }
        return $result;

// place allowed sub-dirs in array, non-recursive
// just only one image

    $dir_array = array();
    foreach (osc_opendir($root_images_dir) as $file) {
      if ($file['is_dir']) {
        $img_dir_products_image = substr($file['name'], strlen($root_images_dir));
        $drop_array[] = array('id' => $img_dir_products_image,
                              'text' => $img_dir_products_image
                             );
      }
    }

echo HTML::selectMenu('directory_products_image', $drop_array);

// second dropdown
// for the image gallery

// gallery
// lecture des fichiers
    $dir_array = array();
    foreach (osc_opendir($root_images_dir) as $file1) {
      if ($file1['is_dir']) {
        $img_dir = substr($file1['name'], strlen($root_images_dir));
        $drop_array[] = array('id' => $img_dir,
                              'text' => $img_dir
                              );
      }   
    }

     echo '<div class="row"><span class="col-xs-3">'.TEXT_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_DIRECTORY. '&nbsp;' . HTML::selectMenu('directory', $drop_array) . '</span></div>';
     echo TEXT_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_NEW_FOLDER_GALLERY . HTML::inputField('new_directory','','class="input-small"') .'<br /><br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting it twice, because you're ADDING it twice:

```
          $result[] = $file;
                 ^^---append filename to array

        $result = array_merge($result, osc_opendir($path . $filename));
                              ^^^^^^^--- add it yet again
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I rewrite my problem, I hope the explanation is better now.